# plone.directives form - passing variables with a redirect

Tags: plone

I have a plone form that basically gets search terms, performs a search, and then directs the user to another form. For this second form, I need to pass a couple variables.

```
class MySearch(form.SchemaForm):
  grok.context(IMyContext)
  grok.name('my-search')
  ignoreContext = True

  schema = ISearchSchema

  @button.buttonAndHandler(_(u'Search Method'))
  def searchMethod(self, action):
    """ group update/removal """
    data, errors = self.extractData()
    if errors:
      self.status = self.formErrorsMessage
      return

    results = somecall(data['term'])

    if results:
      self.request.set('myvar',results['myvar'])
      self.request.response.redirect('@@my-results')
    else:
      IStatusMessage(self.request).addStatusMessage(_(u"No results found"),"info")
    return
```

This doesn't work - I guess a new request is generated so myvar is immediately lost. I could put this in a query string and include it in the redirect, but would prefer to send it as POST data if possible. I also tried something like

```
return getMultiAdapter((self.context,self.request),name='my-results')()
```

to see if I could use that as a starting point to passing in variables, but that just returns me to my-search.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters set on the request object are not taken into account (nor should they) when issuing a redirect.

Append a query string to the redirection URL instead; [`urllib.urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) does the job admirably:

```
from urllib import urlencode

self.request.response.redirect('@@my-results?' + urlencode({'myvar': results['myvar']}))
```

The `.redirect()` call returns a [303 See Other response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) with the URL you passed in the the method as the `Location` header; the browser then opens that new location, and will include any GET parameters you added to the URL.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing for now, but do I have an option to send it to the next form besides .redirect()? Perhaps a better way to put it all: I was hoping for something like the old Controller Python Script/Template where you could set values in the "state" bind, return the state, and it would handle all of the traversal/redirection for you, while passing those values.

Comment: You'll have to do that manually here, I'm afraid. Look up the other view, and render it (by calling the view object) and return that, *or* the redirect from my answer.